# How do I filter out gear-icon XHR requests in DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there negative filtering pattern to hide this type of requests?
I don't mean *by domain* - in case they would be sent to multiple domains, I would like to filter them all in one go.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

That's probably a request from a service worker or web worker.

In [Chrome 74](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/devtools#swfilters) DevTools introduced the `is:service-worker-initiated` and `is:service-worker-intercepted` filters. If you add the negative filters to those, e.g. `-is:service-worker-initiated -is:service-worker-intercepted` that may hide all of the service worker requests.

If the requests are coming from a web worker I'm not sure if there's any way to filter them out.

Comment: Yeah, probably. I don't have that app here with me, but thanks for the info - will check it out. What would the team say if we had a right-click menu item "Hide requests like this..."? and some way of persistence - to enable switching between type of work you need to do during dev time.

Comment: Thanks! `-is:service-worker-intercepted` removes simple XHR too, so use only `-is:service-worker-initiated` to hide Service Workers requests.

Comment: I wish there was a button to apply this filter, as those requests are so annoying while inspecting PWAs.